# The visited link color on our mainsite theme is missing because --theme-primary-color-300/800 are not set

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, css

Visited link text on mainsite is broken—the text is showing up black instead of the usual visted color. For example, on [How to ask](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):

[image: the link text in a paragraph is black]

This is because apparently `--theme-primary-color-300` and `-800` are not set, as reported by Firefox's inspector here:

[image: a screenshot of the CSS]

(it's not very clear here, but I'm hovering over one of these undefined variables, and that "not set" text is part of a dialog telling me, well, that the variable's not set. The variables being grey indicates it's undefined.)

Comment: Experienced the same issue in windows chrome and iOS safari.

Comment: FWIW, the color on mobile is now white instead of whatever the previous color was as well

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll be looking into this today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed and is now live across the network. Yesterday we rolled out a behind-the-scenes update to unify how many components across the network are themed. It looks like a slight typo made it into the code that sets visited and hovered link colors, causing them to revert to their default values instead of using the correct values from the site's theme. This has been corrected and steps have been taken to ensure that this typo didn't occur anywhere else in the product.

Comment: It's working again! Thanks very much Ben. :D